# How to show children view without router-view parent view in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to show a child route view in another view and not inside the parent  route view,
i have the next routes in an the module of vue-router:

```
const users = {
    path: '/users',
    name: 'users',
    component: Users,
    children: [
      { path: ':user', 
        name: 'user', 
        component: User,
        children: [
          { path: 'profile', name: 'profile', component: Profile },
          { path: 'events', name: 'events', component: Events }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
export default home
```

When entering the path /users/:user shows me the children view inside the parent view through the router-view

```
<!-- users.vue -->
<!-- path: /users -->
<template>
  <div v-if="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
    <router-link :to="`/users/${user.name}`">{{ user.name }}</router-link>
  </div>
  <!-- Here shows the children view  -->
  <!-- path: /users/:user/ -->
  <router-view/>
</template>
```

I need it to be shown directly in another independent view and not inside the parent view, 
It would be something like this:

```
<!-- users.vue -->
<!-- path: /users -->
<template>
  <div v-if="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
    <router-link :to="`/users/${user.name}`">{{ user.name }}</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- user.vue -->
<!-- path: /users/:user -->
<template>
  <h1>{{ this.$route.params.name }}</h1>
</template>
```

If you could help me, thank you
regards

Comment: create a separate route for the user route, not the children of users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate route for the user route, not the children of users

```
    const users = [{
      path: '/users',
      name: 'users',
      component: Users,

    },
    {
      path: 'users/:user',
      name: 'user',
      component: User,
      children: [
        { path: 'profile', name: 'profile', component: Profile },
        { path: 'events', name: 'events', component: Events }
      ]
    }
    ]
```

Comment: this shows `Non-nested routes must include a leading slash character.` warning

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but maybe it will help someone.

You can make users and user do at the one level

```
const users = {
    path: '/users',
    children: [
       {
          path: '', 
          name: 'users', 
          component: Users,
       },
       {
          path: ':user', 
          name: 'user', 
          component: User,
          children: [
             { path: 'profile', name: 'profile', component: Profile },
             { path: 'events', name: 'events', component: Events }
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```